Excited states: S0, S1, S2 interpretation
Good morning, everyone. I have a question about molecular excitation. I'm studying photochemistry, and I came across the terms excited states S₀, S₁, and S₂. Initially, I thought that S₁ represented the electronic configuration where the electron is promoted from the Highest Occupied Molecular Orbital (HOMO) to the Lowest Unoccupied Molecular Orbital (LUMO), while S₂ would refer to the excitation of the HOMO to the next orbital above the LUMO. This seemed especially accurate to me when studying the excitation of ethanal, where the S₁ state corresponds to the transition from HOMO to LUMO.
However, when I worked with a more complex molecule and performed an excitation calculation using Time-Dependent Density Functional Theory (TDDFT) for the first ten excited states (S₁, S₂, ... S₁₀), I obtained results that were very different from my expectations.
This is my molecule MO diagram to Ground State (S0):

These are my results of TDDFT:

In the S₁ excited state, transitions occur from the HOMO orbital (orbital 26) to the LUMO (orbital 27) and also to an orbital above the LUMO (orbital 29).
Interestingly, in the S₂ state, transitions involve orbitals significantly below the HOMO, such as orbitals 21 and 24, reaching orbitals much higher than the first one next to the LUMO.
Initially, I thought this was incorrect, as I expected the S₂ state to transition from HOMO (26) to the orbital immediately following the LUMO (28). However, the calculations reveal that the S₂ state consists of four different transitions.
I would like to clarify that the correct interpretation of the excited states S₀, S₁, and S₂ relates to the energy needed for a transition to occur, rather than the specific type of orbital involved, as is the case with atomic transitions.
In other words, if the transition from orbital 26 to orbital 29 requires energy X, and this energy corresponds to the Sn excited state, then this transition would be classified as part of the Sn state.

What more complex molecule? What software?

Look for ex. here how excited states are more precisely described.
